# Folder added it .gitignore still showing up in the Git changes

Tags: git, gitignore

Ok so I recently upgraded to Angular 13 and now I have this folder name ".angular".

I have added its entry in `.gitignore` file as `.angular/cache` since it don't want to track it, but files inside it are always shown in git changes as Untracked files.

Almost every answer on StackOverflow tells to run the following commands.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

All this does is staging the untracked file and then making a commit out of them. My `.angular` folder is still being tracked. It is still not greyed out like node_modules which means git isn't ignoring it.

Should I be doing anything different?

Comment: What's the exact line and in which `.gitignore` that should match the `.angular` directory? Is it maybe already added to `git`? Try [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to debug this.

Comment: I have added this line .angular/cache below the node_module folder line in .gitignore. @acran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are other folders/files in `.angular` and you only ignore the folder `cache` with `.angular/cache` in the `.gitignore`-file, the `.angular` folder would be continue tracked.

So you must ignore the whole `.angular` folder with `.angular/` in `.gitignore`.

After this, the `.angular` folder would be greyed out like the `node_module` folder as you mentioned.

Comment: I don't mind .angular folder itself being tracked, but git is tracking every file inside the cache folder too despite the fact that I have explicitly mentioned .angular.cache in .gitignore for it to be ignored.

Comment: So you question isn‘t really clear… But the problem will be the folder-structure and your `.gitignore` entry is not the same as it is on your angular-project. Find out the folder-structure with `pwd` in `cache` folder and copy the path up to git-root in `.gitignore`.

Comment: thanks @SwissCodeMen . I added .angular/ to .gitignore. and it removed n number of untracked files I was not willing to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `.gitignore` in the root folder of your repository, I would try:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo
echo ".angular/cached/">>.gitignore
git rm -r --cached .angular/cached/
git add .
git commit -m "Remove and ignore .angular/cached
```